# How to use namespaces when writing XML file with SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I’m writing a Google products RSS feed with SimpleXML in PHP. I’ve got my products coming from the database and creating the RSS file fine, but having problems when it comes to namespaces.

I’ve Googled and search Stack Overflow and come across dozens of posts of how to parse XML feeds containing namespaces, but my issue is actually *authoring* an XML file with a namespace.

Here is what the file *should* look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version ="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <!-- content -->
</rss>
```

And here is my code:

```
<?php

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss></rss>');
$xml->addAttribute('version', '2.0');

$xml->addChild('channel');
$xml->channel->addChild('title', 'Removed');
$xml->channel->addChild('description', 'Removed');
$xml->channel->addChild('link', 'Removed');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $item = $xml->channel->addChild('item');
    $item->addChild('title', htmlspecialchars($product['title']));
    $item->addChild('description', htmlspecialchars($product['title']));
    $item->addChild('link', $product['url']);
    $item->addChild('id', $product['product_id']);
    $item->addChild('price', $product['price_latest']);
    $item->addChild('brand', $product['range']);
    $item->addChild('condition', 'new');
    $item->addChild('image_link', $product['image']);
}
```

How do I introduce the `g` namespace, both the `xmlns` declaration in the root `rss` element, and then as a prefix for `id`, `price`, `brand`, `condition` and `image_link` in each `item` element?

Comment: I highly recommend using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this instead. SimpleXML is just that - *simple*. What you are doing has now left the realms of simple. You need a full-featured API for this.

Comment: Have you got an example of how I would add a namespace with DOM?

Comment: @MartinBean There is an example in [manual for DOMDocument's createElementNS](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.createelementns.php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
<?php

    $nsUrl = 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0';

    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    $rootNode = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('rss'));
    $rootNode->setAttribute('version', '2.0');
    $rootNode->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:g', $nsUrl);

    $channelNode = $rootNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('channel'));
    $channelNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('title', 'Removed'));
    $channelNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('description', 'Removed'));
    $channelNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('link', 'Removed'));

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $itemNode = $channelNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('item'));
        $itemNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('title'))->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($product['title']));
        $itemNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('description'))->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($product['title']));
        $itemNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('link'))->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($product['url']));
        $itemNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('g:id'))->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($product['product_id']));
        $itemNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('g:price'))->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($product['price_latest']));
        $itemNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('g:brand'))->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($product['range']));
        $itemNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('g:condition'))->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('new'));
        $itemNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('g:image_link'))->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($product['image']));
    }

    echo $doc->saveXML();
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5ruybP)

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Perfect! Just managed to write a working solution myself that’s very similar to yours: https://gist.github.com/4344973

Comment: @MartinBean Cool :-) Only real diff between yours and mine is that I use explicit text node creation for the dynamic values, which is (IMHO) the best way to deal with escaping entities, because you can pass the raw data in and it will be auto-escaped without messing around with `htmlspecialchars()`. However I admit it does make it *even more* verbose - DOM is not a succinct API, but it is the most flexible one available.

Comment: Good to know, since I actually do have the product title etc wrapped in `htmlspecialchars()` in the actual code! I’ll replace that with the method of explicitly creating a text node, as you have done.

Answer (score 12):

This *can* been done using the SimpleXMLElement interface.  IMHO this is a hack of the dodgiest order, but it works for now.

The key point being that it works as follows, *for now*, but may not continue to work.  As such I'm in no way recommending this over the accepted answer by @DaveRandom.  Rather, I'm including this answer here so that others in future can read this and save themselves some time searching for a SimpleXMLElement way of doing it, and just go with DaveRandom's DOM based approach :-)

You can "trick" the parser to stop it from dropping your `g:` namespace prefix from your element names, by putting a "rubbish" prefix prior to your real one, eg `"blah:g:condition"`.

I've seen variations of this answer for use in attribute prefixes, but not for element prefixes.  And those all seem to suggest using `"xmlns:yourPrefix:yourAttribute"` and passing in the fully qualified names space as the third parameter, where in reality (at least, from my own personal testing) the `xmlns:` part can be pretty much anything (including whitespace!) prior to a colon `:`, but there has to be *something* prior to that first colon, ie `":g:condition"` won't work.  And unless you actually create a node that declares the namespace and prefix, the rendered XML would be invalid (ie the namespace prefix you hack in against your elements will have no declaration).

So, based on your original code, you'd do the following.  Note also the explicit addition of the namespace in the root node declaration (although this can probably be done via the API - but why bother?).

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" />'); // May as well chuck the google ns in the root element declaration here, while we're at it, rather than adding it via a separate attribute.
$xml->addAttribute('version', '2.0'); 
// $xml->addAttribute('hack:xmlns:g','http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'); //Or could do this instead...

$xml->addChild('channel');
$xml->channel->addChild('title', 'Removed');
$xml->channel->addChild('description', 'Removed');
$xml->channel->addChild('link', 'Removed');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $item = $xml->channel->addChild('item');
    $item->addChild('title', htmlspecialchars($product['title']));
    $item->addChild('description', htmlspecialchars($product['title']));
    $item->addChild('link', $product['url']);
    $item->addChild('hack:g:id', $product['product_id']);
    $item->addChild('hack:g:price', $product['price_latest']);
    $item->addChild('hack:g:brand', $product['range']);
    $item->addChild('hack:g:condition', 'new');
    $item->addChild('hack:g:image_link', $product['image']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by adding the namespace declaration into the root element creation along with adding the namespace to the `addChild` function.

The modification to the original code:

```
$products[] = array(
  "title" => "Foobar",
  "description" => "Foo",
  "url" => "https://f.oo.bar",
  "product_id" => "00001",
  "price_latest" => "$3.50",
  "range" => "Foo",
  "image" => "https://f.oo.bar/image.tiff",
);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"/>');
$xml->addAttribute('version', '2.0');

$xml->addChild('channel');
$xml->channel->addChild('title', 'Removed');
$xml->channel->addChild('description', 'Removed');
$xml->channel->addChild('link', 'Removed');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $item = $xml->channel->addChild('item');
    $item->addChild('title', htmlspecialchars($product['title']));
    $item->addChild('description', htmlspecialchars($product['title']));
    $item->addChild('link', $product['url']);
    $item->addChild('id', $product['product_id'], "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
    $item->addChild('price', $product['price_latest'], "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
    $item->addChild('brand', $product['range'], "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
    $item->addChild('condition', 'new', "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
    $item->addChild('image_link', $product['image'], "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
}

print_r($xml->asXML());
```

Would yield the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Removed</title>
    <description>Removed</description>
    <link>Removed</link>
    <item>
      <title>Foobar</title>
      <description>Foobar</description><link/>
      <g:id>00001</g:id>
      <g:price>$3.50</g:price>
      <g:brand>Foo</g:brand>
      <g:condition>new</g:condition>
      <g:image_link>https://f.oo.bar/image.tiff</g:image_link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```